# Accessing container by domain name

Tags: docker, networking, dns

hey guys I have a docker container A with a domain name attached to it on a host B with a domain name attached to it as well.....how can I access the said container A via A's domain name rather than an B's ip address or domain name from computer C on the host B's local network

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it you need to establish a network service (I.e, compose file), though if you are working with a docker file (e.g, ver. docker 1.x < 2) you typically issue a command or execute a script. In either case, I’ll need to create a new network service and bridge ports (I.e, expose port) to make them accessible:

A <-> B -> C

Check out the documentation:

https://docs.docker.com/network/

Hope that helped.

Comment: @AigoLamda not really it did not. I got A and B to work using DNS Proxy Server container. I'm trying to get C which is a local network with A but not B to see B, however, I need to access it via www.domain.url and not ip:port

Comment: Sorry, if it wasn't much help. I also found [link](https://docs.docker.com/datacenter/ucp/2.1/guides/user/services/use-domain-names-to-access-services/) maybe this would help. If you are trying to access a container via domain name using a container service. The examples a bit crud but it can be extrapolated.